# Error in (function (file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'", dec = ".", : > 'file' must be a character string or connection

Tags: r

I am trying to analyse my data using the proloc package in R.I need to somehow pass my data to readMSnSet.

My data is csv files located in my computer which is different from how they do in in the vignette example (f0 <- dir(system.file("extdata", package = "pRolocdata"),
full.names = TRUE,
pattern = "pr800866n_si_004-rep1.csv"))

```
>library("MSnbase")
>library("pRoloc")
>library("pRolocdata")


> ## The quantitation data, from the original data     
> f1<-read.csv("exprescsv.csv",header=T)
> ##Feature meta-data, from the original data  
> f2<-read.csv("fdatacsv.csv",header=T)
> ## Sample meta-data, a new file  
> f3<-read.csv("fractions.csv",header=T)
> tan2009r1 <- readMSnSet(exprsFile = f1,featureDataFile = f2, phenoDataFile = f3,sep = ",")                  

>Error in (function (file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'", dec = ".",  : 
>  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Please let me know if you understand this error as I am desperate for help at this point

Comment: You don't need to read the csv (i.e. no need to `read.csv()`). Just pass the path to `exprsFile`, `phenoDataFile`, and `featureDataFile`

Comment: hI @langtang thanks for your answer. I tried that before and it shows this error:

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 5 did not have 12 elements

Comment: Sounds like one of your csv files is misformatted.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. How could I check this ? or what does it mean ?

Comment: "line 5 did not have 12 elements" - csv formatting expects each line in the file (each row if you think of it as a table or spreadsheet) to have the same number of entries.  I have seen this error before when files had a subheading, for example.  An easy way to check is open each in a text editor or excel/sheets.

Comment: But I mean if you check here the example https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/pRoloc/inst/doc/v01-pRoloc-tutorial.html their example metadata file pdataCsv is a metadata file that obviously does not have the same number of rows. The  other two files f1 and f2 have identical number of rows I checked.